# Quick way to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g(x+y)\, dx$ for $y \in [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, computational-mathematics

When we want to compute:
$$
h(y) = \int_0^y f(x) g(y-x)\, dx,
$$
for $y \in [0,\infty)$ we can make use of a Fast Fourrier Transform to quickly compute these integrals. I have a similar problem where I want to compute:
$$
h(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g(x+y)\, dx
$$
for all $y \in [0,\infty)$. Is there a similar trick that can be used here?

Comment: Is there a long way?

Comment: Simply loop over all values of $y$ and compute the integral